# I am finding it hard to understand Boolean Logic in code

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

The code below has the Python code with Boolean expressions. Please help me understand the logic in them and how they are bringing out the different results.

```
#code 1
for row in range(7):#Code to print rows
    for col in range(5):#Code to print columns 
        if ((col == 0 or col == 4) or row!=0): 
            print("*", end = "")
        else:
            print(end = " ")
    print()
```

```
#Code 2
for row in range(7):#Code to print rows
    for col in range(5):#Code to print columns 
        if ((col ==0 and col == 4) and row!=0): 
            print("*", end = "")
        else:
            print(end = " ")
    print()
```

```
#Code 3
for row in range(7):#Code to print rows
    for col in range(5):#Code to print columns 
        if ((col ==0 or col == 4) and row!=0): 
            print("*", end = "")
        else:
            print(end = " ")
    print()
```

```
#code 4
for row in range(7):#Code to print rows
    for col in range(5):#Code to print columns 
        if ((col ==0 and col == 4) or row!=0): 
            print("*", end = "")
        else:
            print(end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: You should start by learning [the basics of boolean logic](https://www.codecademy.com/resources/blog/what-is-boolean-logic/) and then ask specific questions here.

Answer (score 0):

**The four codes have in common:**
Two nested loops go through `7x5 = 35` different cases.
For each case, a Boolean expression is evaluated. Depending on the result, a '*' is printed for `true` and a gap/space for `false`.

**In English, the four Boolean expressions can be described as follows:**

```
1: ((col == 0 or col == 4) or row!=0)
```

This is true when either `col` is `0` or `4`, or `row` is unequal to `0`.
In other words: For the first `row`, there are two '*' columns.
For the remaining six rows, outcome is '*' for all columns

```
2: ((col == 0 and col == 4) and row!=0)
```

This can only be true for the last six rows.
But `col` cannot have two different values at the same time.
Therefore, the expression is always `false`. It is a contradiction.

```
3: ((col == 0 or col == 4) and row!=0)
```

This can only be `true` for two of the five columns.
It is `false` for the first `row`.

```
4: ((col == 0 and col == 4) or row!=0)
```

The `col` part is a contradiction and thus always `false`.
But the `row` part is `true` for the last six rows.
Therefore, one blank rows followed by six rows of '*' are printed